# Eclipse keep crashing (Android, Mac)

Tags: android, eclipse, macos

I'm having a problem with Eclipse keep crashing on Macbook Pro (Retina, Late 2013, Mavericks). The crash will happen when I plug an Android device (usb debugging mode : on) to the laptop, which, will generate a lot of log message in logcat. Then, a random moment later Eclipse will stop responding and crash with following exception.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.android.ddmuilib.logcat.LogCatPanel.updateUnreadCount(LogCatPanel.java:1212)
at com.android.ddmuilib.logcat.LogCatPanel.bufferChanged(LogCatPanel.java:1168)
at com.android.ddmuilib.logcat.LogCatPanel.reloadLogBuffer(LogCatPanel.java:1196)
at com.android.ddmuilib.logcat.LogCatPanel.updateAppliedFilters(LogCatPanel.java:1136)
at com.android.ddmuilib.logcat.LogCatPanel.filterSelectionChanged(LogCatPanel.java:1117)
at com.android.ddmuilib.logcat.LogCatPanel.access$1400(LogCatPanel.java:98)
at com.android.ddmuilib.logcat.LogCatPanel$6.widgetSelected(LogCatPanel.java:623)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:248)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4136)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1458)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1481)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1466)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Widget.java:1271)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3982)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3621)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1053)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:942)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:86)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:588)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:543)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
```

Any idea how to resolve this or at least disable all the log message which not related to the running package (message generate too quick, won't be able to read anyway)

Best

P.S. I have 1 user-define message filter which filter tagged message.

Comment: It's a NullPointerException... where's the code?

Answer (score 1):

Based on that stack trace, it's crashing in the filtering code. Try removing or recreating that filter.